# How to find current file location in C#?

Tags: c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I wanted to find where is my .exe file when it runs.
for example it's location is *C:\User*  and you need to know this when the app starts.

Answer (score 1):

```
string path = "";
path = System.AppContext.BaseDirectory;
```

With this code you are able to find where is your .exe file is running from.